# Why must I set "trasnclude: true" in an Angular DDO?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

**I know what `transclude: true` does**, but I've always wondered: "why must I put `transclude: true` in my DDO as well as a `ng-transclude` in my template?".

What's going on internally that forces angular to be redundant? Is it security/XSS protection? Performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ngTransclude documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) explains the separation of the two (emphasis mine):

> [ngTransclude is a] directive that marks the insertion point for the transcluded DOM of the **nearest parent** directive that uses transclusion.

This means:

- `transclude: true` indicates that the directive makes its content available for transclusion.
- `ng-transclude` indicates where the content should go.

A directive with transclusion enabled doesn't actually have to handle the transclusion of it's own content. It can let a child element choose where to put the transcluded content.

Here is a (trivial) example that shows how transclusion can be handled by a child directive inside a parent:

```
<!-- Application template -->
<parent-el>
    <h1>Transcluded content</h1>
</parent-el>


<!-- <parent-el> template -->
<p>I am the parent element</p>
<child-el></child-el>


<!-- <child-el> template -->
<p>I am the child element</p>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

This is how the content will then be rendered in the page:

```
<!-- Rendered content -->
<parent-el>
    <p>I am the parent element</p>
    <child-el>
        <p>I am the child element</p>
        <div>
            <h1>Transcluded content</h1>
        </div>
    </child-el>
</parent-el>
```

Answer (score 1):

> There are three kinds of transclusion depending upon whether you want to transclude just the contents of the directive's element, the entire element or multiple parts of the element contents:
>
> - `true` - transclude the content (i.e. the child nodes) of the directive's element.
> - `'element'` - transclude the whole of the directive's element including any directives on this element that defined at a lower priority than this directive. When used, the template property is ignored.
> - `{...}` (an object hash): - map elements of the content onto transclusion "slots" in the template.

-- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion